# When asking for input in Python, is there a way to check if each key input is within a valid set of inputs?

Tags: python, input

I am trying to accept input of just phone numbers. The user is prompted to input a number. One method is to accept any input, and after the user has entered the input, check if it's a valid phone number. However, instead of checking the input *after* the user presses enter, I would like to check each input *as* the user is pressing each key. If the key is a number then it will be accepted. For instance if the user types 1234a, then the input will only accept and display 1234 and pressing a or any invalid key will not result in any behavior.

Comment: This would require a key listener of some sort, an easier solution may be to take user input and trim out any invalid characters (non-digits in this case)

Comment: I've never tried it myself, but this looks promising: [How to read a single character from the user?](/q/510357/4518341)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think this might help you. What it does is to take specific user input in the form of:

1. Only digits
2. Using the following pattern: XXX-XXX-XXXX.

This can obviously be crafted to specific number formats including country code and/or local number patterns according to your needs.

```
# import RegEx module
import re

def phone_checker(phone_number):
    print("Enter phone number as XXX-XXX-XXXX")
    while True:
        pattern = r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}' #create a phone number pattern
        res = re.findall(pattern,phone_number) #search for pattern in user input
        to_string = ''.join(res) #convert to string

        if phone_number in to_string:
            print("Number accepted!")
            break
        else:
            print("Number not recognized. Try again.")

phone_checker(phone_number=input("Enter phone number: "))
```